# is io_service_.stop() only required when io_service_.run() previously called

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I implement a tcp client using boost asio and synchronous socket.

I'm wondering if I have to call io_service_.stop() after (or before?) shutdown/closed my socket?

Comment: Do you have more than one socket? Are they all sharing a single `io_service`? What do you think would happen to the other sockets event handling if you stop the service when one socket disconnects? On the other hand, if you have only a single socket (for example in a client program with a single connection to a server), will the program continue after the socket is closed? Will it be possible to connect to another (or the same) server? Why stop the service then, if you have to restart it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will stop itself when there is no work to do, which should be the case once all the sockets etc. have been closed (unless you use a `work` object to keep it alive). Only call `stop` if you want it to stop while asynchronous operations are still pending.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

If you don't need your `socket` any more and the `socket` is still opened:

- close the `socket`.

If you don't need your `io_service` any more and the `io_service` is still working:

- stop the `io_service`.

If you've been using your `io_service` only for one `socket` and you don't need the `socket` any more:

- close the `socket`,
- then stop the `io_service` if the `io_service` is still working.